How to get datepicker to show today's date in a new form using php
I'm using PHP 8.2 and datepicker.
I have a form. It has two date fields, which both use the datepicker class.  When the page loads, the form is empty (new record). But, the date fields default to 1970-01-01.  How can I get these date fields to be either: 1) Today's date (current date) or, 2) empty?
In the code (below), I use value="<?= isset($start_date) ? $start_date : $today; ?>"  so if the form doesn't pass validation, I re-show the form with the values entered.
Code:
// from new form

<?php
$today = date('m/d/Y');
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
      <label for="start_date"><strong>Start Date:</strong>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="<?= isset($start_date) ? $start_date : $today; ?>" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
      <label for="end_date"><strong>End Date:</strong>
      <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="end_date" id="end_date" value="<?= isset($end_date) ? $end_date : $today; ?>" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

....

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>


I tried the following from a thread I saw, but it did not work:
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    });
  });
</script>

// and 

<script>
  $( function() {
    let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en", {year:"numeric", day:"2-digit", month:"2-digit"});

    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: date });

  });
</script>


Thanks for any help.
Cheers!

I'm assuming this is a jQuery date picker? Any chance you can just use a native HTML5 one? https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/JjgWOyM

Run var_dump($start_date); to ensure it contains what you think it does.

With this code isset($start_date) you just test if the variable exists. But in my opinion this variable exists and it contains '1970-01-01'. Like @AlexHowansky says, make a var_dump on this variable.

"did not work" doesn't tell us anything useful. What specific behaviour did you observe when you added this code in? We're going to assume you'll have done basic debugging such as dumping your variable values, checking the console for errors, checking the generated output of the page and so on, and are going to tell us what you observed. Remember we can't see what's in all your variables necessarily, therefore we can't always predict what the code will do with them.

But anyway, those jQuery snippets just set up a datepicker widget and set the date the widget shows when you open it. They don't pre-populate the textbox. As above, the most likely problem here is that $start_date doesn't contain what you're assuming it does. Which is why you should debug your code and check all the relevant variables...it's hard to work out why you didn't do that before going to all the trouble of posting a question.
